# Is there a way to make Ubuntu "forget" a network connection?

Tags: wireless, internet, wpa

Is there a file or something that holds the data for the internet connections?

Comment: Says it's a duplicate of "How to connect and disconnect to a network manually in terminal?" but not really: this is Ubuntu, there ought to be a way to do it without a terminal.

Answer (score 35):

In Ubuntu, take a look at the following folder: `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`.

The files in here should contain the network connections' settings Network Manager has saved: network card used to connect to the network, SSID name, wireless key/passphrase, IP configuration method, etc.

Of course, the files can only be read as root. Using your normal account, you cannot open the files and read the settings.

The files cannot be deleted by another user than root. To delete a settings file, an administrator would execute the following commands in a terminal:

```
cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
rm <filename>
```

where `<filename>` would be replaced by the actual filename. To delete all the settings files in one time, an administrator would use the `*` joker as the filename.

Comment: They need to make this better. It should be easier. some one should make it a right click "forget network". Why is this not a thing?
i sudo nano this file and it's empty. this is so frustrating.

Comment: @PatrickW.McMahon get used to do thing with the terminal. It will help you get over your frustation and you'll learn a valuable skill

Comment: In my case I had to restart the computer before it applied the change

Answer (score 12):

You can click on the Network Icon --> Edit Connections, this will let you delete previous Wireless or Wired configurations.

Comment: Doesn't exist anymore on 18.10