# 18.04 Cannot disconnect from wifi network (eduroam)

Tags: wireless

I have set up my linux laptop to use the infamous and astoundingly bad **eduroam** network, using their [CAT software](https://cat.eduroam.org/#) *(it's a python script).*

Now I can't connect to other wifi networks or even disconnect from this network whenever it is available.

[image]

I click on connect, and nothing happens. There is no button to disconnect from the network.

I tried removing the file in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/284018/is-there-a-way-to-make-ubuntu-forget-a-network-connection). It still won't forget the network.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `nmcli connection down id edo.wifi.2407450`  I hope this was the connection you ment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disconnect from the network after removing the file from `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`, I had to restart the network manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

and then it worked.